# What is an example of a covering map of a Riemann Surface of log(z)?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading a book of [1], and on pages 206 ~ 207 in Section 4.19, the authors gave 5 examples of a covering space for Riemann surfaces that we studies so far.
One of which is a covering space of a Riemann Surface of log(z), but didn't quite explain what a covering map is there.
Specifically, the text goes like

> Riemann surface of log(z) is a covering surface of $\Sigma \setminus \{0, \infty \} $, with infinitely many sheets.

#### My question

I was not sure what a covering map here is..

#### My guess

As, log is going from the covering space to the base space, I assume the exponential map is a covering map here as it's going from the covering space to the base space as the inverse of log?

Am I guessing correctly..?

#### Reference

[1] Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe it's easier to think about the analogous line covering the circle $e^{2\pi i x}:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing an easier example!!